# Java - How do I split an array into four separate arrays?

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have an array which contains a string of numbers such as: 1011

and I wanted to split it up into four separate arrays containing each of those values. How do I do this?

```
String [] array = {1,0,1,1}; 

//would I do something like this:

array.substring(0,4)
```

Comment: What's the problem with just using `array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]`?

Comment: It's for a computer architecture project and each array represents a binary number. In the end I need to be able to do logic operations on these and the only way I can think of doing this is to split an array like this

Comment: The literal '1' is not compatible with the String type.  Do you mean "1","0","1","1" or do you mean for the array to be of type 'int'?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [Arrays.copyOfRange(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 would be to simply create a new array for each item in the array you have... could be done generically like this:

```
public <T> List<T[]> splitEachItemIntoOwnArray(T[] original) {
  List<T[]> result = new ArrayList<T[]>();
  if (original == null) return result;

  for (T t : original) {
    result.add((T[])new Object[] {t});
  }

  return result;
}
```

Option 2, you could also achieve this generically with the Arrays.copyOfRange() method:

```
public <T> List<T[]> splitEachItemIntoOwnArray2(T[] original) {
    List<T[]> result = new ArrayList<T[]>();
    if (original == null) return result;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(original,i,i+1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Options 1 and 2 work if you always want the each item of the original array split into its own array.  If you might want every N items of the original array split into their own, this should work:

```
public <T> List<T[]> splitEachItemIntoOwnArray2(T[] original, int size) {
    List<T[]> result = new ArrayList<T[]>();
    if (original == null) return result;

    int curPos = 0;
    while (curPos < original.length) {
        int remaining = original.length - curPos+1;
        if (remaining <= size) {
            result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(original,curPos,original.length));
        } else {
            result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(original,curPos,curPos+size));
        }
        curPos += size;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] array = {1,0,1,1}; 
    int[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 1);
    int[] array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, 2);
    int[] array3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 2, 3);
    int[] array4 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 3, 4);
    System.out.println(array1[0]);
    System.out.println(array2[0]);
    System.out.println(array3[0]);
    System.out.println(array4[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no splitting afaik, but you can copy it into new arrays using a range

check out copyOfRange

```
static <T,U> T[] copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to, Class<? extends T[]> newType)
```

usage follows:

```
String [] array = {1,0,1,1}; 
// Copies from element 0 to 0
String[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 0);
```